# How to display JSON Array names in a spinner?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I'm working on an app which deals with Theatres and movies running in that theatre. I've successfully parsed the JSON File, thanks to Stack overflow! But I'm stuck on displaying the JSON ARRAY Names on a spinner.

This is the JSON File.

```
{
 "Abirami": [                      //Theatre 1
  {
   "name": "Bairavaa - Tamil"
  },
  {
   "name": "Koditta Idangalai Nirappuga - Tamil"
  },
  {
   "name": "Gautamiputra Satakarni - Telugu"
  },
  {
   "name": "Khaidi No. 150 - Telugu"
  }
 ],
 "AGS_OMR": [                      //Theatre 2
  {
   "name": "Gautamiputra Satakarni - Telugu"
  },
  {
   "name": "Bairavaa - Tamil"
  },
  {
   "name": "xXx: Return Of Xander Cage (3D) - English"
  },
  {
   "name": "OK Jaanu - Hindi"
  },
  {
   "name": "Koditta Idangalai Nirappuga - Tamil"
  }
 ],
 "AGS_TNagar": [                    //Theatre 3
  {
   "name": "xXx: Return Of Xander Cage (3D) - English"
  },
  {
   "name": "Bairavaa - Tamil"
  },
  {
   "name": "OK Jaanu - Hindi"
  },
  {
   "name": "Koditta Idangalai Nirappuga - Tamil"
  }
 ],
 "AGS_Villivakkam": [
  {
   "name": "Bairavaa - Tamil"
  },
  {
   "name": "OK Jaanu - Hindi"
  },
  {
   "name": "Khaidi No. 150 - Telugu"
  },
  {
   "name": "Koditta Idangalai Nirappuga - Tamil"
  }
 ],
 "INOX_Arcot_Road": [
  {
   "name": "Bairavaa - Tamil"
  },
  {
   "name": "Dhuruvangal Pathinaaru - Tamil"
  },
  {
   "name": "Gautamiputra Satakarni - Telugu"
  },
  {
   "name": "xXx: Return Of Xander Cage (3D) - English"
  },
  {
   "name": "Koditta Idangalai Nirappuga - Tamil"
  },
  {
   "name": "OK Jaanu - Hindi"
  },
  {
   "name": "Khaidi No. 150 - Telugu"
  }
 ],
 "INOX_Citi_Centre": [
  {
   "name": "Dhuruvangal Pathinaaru - Tamil"
  },
  {
   "name": "xXx: Return Of Xander Cage (3D) - English"
  },
  {
   "name": "Bairavaa - Tamil"
  },
  {
   "name": "Koditta Idangalai Nirappuga - Tamil"
  },
  {
   "name": "OK Jaanu - Hindi"
  }
 ],
 "LUXE": [
  {
   "name": "Dangal (Tamil) - Tamil"
  },
  {
   "name": "Dangal - Hindi"
  },
  {
   "name": "Live By Night - English"
  },
  {
   "name": "Bairavaa - Tamil"
  },
  {
   "name": "OK Jaanu - Hindi"
  },
  {
   "name": "Khaidi No. 150 - Telugu"
  },
  {
   "name": "Gautamiputra Satakarni - Telugu"
  },
  {
   "name": "Koditta Idangalai Nirappuga - Tamil"
  },
  {
   "name": "Shatamanam Bhavati - Telugu"
  }
 ],
 "mayajaal": [
  {
   "name": "Khaidi No. 150 - Telugu"
  },
  {
   "name": "Bairavaa - Tamil"
  },
  {
   "name": "xXx: Return Of Xander Cage (3D Tamil) - Tamil"
  },
  {
   "name": "xXx: Return Of Xander Cage (3D) - English"
  },
  {
   "name": "Koditta Idangalai Nirappuga - Tamil"
  },
  {
   "name": "Kirik Party - Kannada"
  },
  {
   "name": "Dangal - Hindi"
  },
  {
   "name": "Shatamanam Bhavati - Telugu"
  },
  {
   "name": "Haraamkhor - Hindi"
  },
  {
   "name": "Gautamiputra Satakarni - Telugu"
  }
 ],
 "PVR_Ampa": [
  {
   "name": "xXx: Return Of Xander Cage (3D) - English"
  },
  {
   "name": "Khaidi No. 150 - Telugu"
  },
  {
   "name": "Passengers (3D) - English"
  },
  {
   "name": "Gautamiputra Satakarni - Telugu"
  },
  {
   "name": "Bairavaa - Tamil"
  },
  {
   "name": "OK Jaanu - Hindi"
  },
  {
   "name": "Live By Night - English"
  },
  {
   "name": "Koditta Idangalai Nirappuga - Tamil"
  },
  {
   "name": "Dangal - Hindi"
  },
  {
   "name": "Shatamanam Bhavati - Telugu"
  }
 ],
 "PVR_Velachery": [
  {
   "name": "Dhuruvangal Pathinaaru - Tamil"
  },
  {
   "name": "Khaidi No. 150 - Telugu"
  },
  {
   "name": "Bairavaa - Tamil"
  },
  {
   "name": "OK Jaanu - Hindi"
  },
  {
   "name": "Koditta Idangalai Nirappuga - Tamil"
  },
  {
   "name": "xXx: Return Of Xander Cage (3D) - English"
  },
  {
   "name": "Dangal - Hindi"
  }
 ]
}
```

How to display just the Theatre names like Theatre 1,2,3 and so on in a spinner? The JSON File is present in the Assets folder in Android Studio.

**EDIT: Parsing of JSON file from Assets.**

```
private ArrayList<String> getTheatres(String theatre_results) {
        JSONArray jsonArray = null;
        ArrayList<String> cList = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            InputStream is = getResources().getAssets().open(theatre_results);
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] data = new byte[size];
            is.read(data);
            is.close();
            String json = new String(data, "UTF-8");
            jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
            if (jsonArray != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    cList.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
                   System.out.println("value is "+cList.get(0));
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            je.printStackTrace();
        }
        return cList;
    }
```

Comment: There are a lot of resource out there; search first

Comment: @DegenSharew A small help would be wonderful. I've tried my best searching and hence asked this. Please help.

Comment: please show 
how you parse the JSON  in your code.

Comment: @SanjayChauhan I've added it. Please help!

Comment: you have json object on root not array.

Comment: @junaidhafeez Can you explain? This JSON file was returned by a web scraper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONObject rootJsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
Iterator iterator = rootJsonObject.keys();
   while(iterator.hasNext()){
    //this below key will be the names of your each theater, you may 
    //add it into a list to populate spinner
    String key = (String)iterator.next();
    JsonArray theaterArray = rootJsonObject.getJsonArray(key);
    }
```

after adding all the keys into a list you can populate your spinner fro that list. I would suggest you even a better approach, make a hashmap like this

```
HashMap<String, JsonArray> = new HashMap();
```

add all your data into it, populate your spinner with the hashmap keys and on selection of any of the spinner item you can get all your inside data (theater array) from hashmap against that specific key.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try this asap and let you know!

Comment: np, let me know if you face any problem and accept the answer it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to get all theater names

```
ArrayList<String> theaters = getTheaters(theatre_results);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,theaters);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

private ArrayList<String> getTheatres(String theatre_results) {
        JSONObject jsonObj = null;
        try {
            InputStream is = getResources().getAssets().open(theatre_results);
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] data = new byte[size];
            is.read(data);
            is.close();
            String json = new String(data, "UTF-8");
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            return jsonObject.names();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            je.printStackTrace();
        }
        return cList;
    }
```

Use this list to create adapter and set it to the spinner

Comment: Will try asap and let you know! Thanks.

Comment: You are having a JSONObject but trying to build JSONArray...